# Prune graph nodes that have no path to any of a set of target nodes

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a MultiDIGraph with a large number of nodes.  It has a forest structure with a number of 'initial nodes' if you like.  I have a set of target nodes that I am interested in computing.  I'd like to prune nodes that have no path to any of teh targets.

And - I'm a networks beginner.

Is there a function or algorithm to do it?

I guess I could iteratively start with the targets and get their predecessaors and combine a set and keep doing so until it is stable, and then discard everything except in the set.  But it seems it might be a common requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a special case of DiGraph, I think that Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) can solve this problem easily. If you can ensure that your forest structure is DAG, or remove the loop edge from the graph first using `nx.simple_cycles(G)`, then you can use `ancestors(G, source)` to return all nodes having a path to source in G. Or you can use `descendants(G, source)` if you want to check in the opposite way.

See the [networkx.algorithms.dag.ancestors](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.ancestors.html#networkx.algorithms.dag.ancestors) documentation